# Ramanujan-type trigonometric identities with cube roots, generalizing $\sqrt[3]{\cos(2\pi/7)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos(4\pi/7)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos(8\pi/7)}$

Tags: trigonometry, galois-theory

Ramanujan found the following trigonometric identity
\begin{equation}
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{2\pi}7\bigr)}+
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{4\pi}7\bigr)}+
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{8\pi}7\bigr)}=
\sqrt[3]{\tfrac{5-3\sqrt[3]7}2}
\end{equation}
(see e.g. [Ramanujan — For Lowbrows](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Berndt-Bhargava644-656.pdf), (3.7) and around, for details and an analogue for 9 instead of 7).

> Are there analogous identities for all primes $p$ of the form $3k+1$ instead of 7?

Let me try to explain what I mean. As I've learned from S. Markelov, for $p=13$
\begin{multline}
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{2\pi}{13}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{10\pi}{13}\bigr)}+
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{4\pi}{13}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{6\pi}{13}\bigr)}+
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{8\pi}{13}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{12\pi}{13}\bigr)}=\\
\sqrt[3]{\tfrac{3\sqrt[3]{13}-7}2}
\end{multline}
and there are close analogues for all $p$ of the form $n^2+n+1$. For example, for $p=43=6^2+6+1$ three groups of numerators are {2, 4, 8, 16, 22, 32, 42}, {6, 10, 12, 20, 24, 38, 40}, {14, 18, 26, 28, 30, 34, 36} and the sum is $\sqrt[3]{\frac{3\sqrt[3]{86}-13}2}$.

So it looks like there is some pattern reminding of... *quadratic Gauss sums*, perhaps.

---

For any $p=3k+1$ one can partition $\mathbb F_p^\times$ into three groups, corresponding to $\mathbb F_p^\times/\mathbb F_p^{\times3}\cong\mathbb Z/3$ — and this is precisely the partitions from the last paragraph. This explains what LHS should look like. And indeed, at least for $p=19$ [there is an identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=461077) 
\begin{multline}
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{7\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{11\pi}{19}\bigr)}+
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{3\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{5\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{17\pi}{19}\bigr)}+\\
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{9\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{13\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{15\pi}{19}\bigr)}=\\
\sqrt[3]{\tfrac12-3\sqrt[3]7+\tfrac32\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{49}+18\sqrt[3]7-25}+\tfrac32\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{49}+18\sqrt[3]7-44}}
\end{multline}
which is closely related to the fact that [$2 \left( \cos \frac{4\pi}{19} + \cos \frac{6\pi}{19}+\cos \frac{10\pi}{19} \right)$ is a root of the equation $\sqrt{ 4+ \sqrt{ 4 + \sqrt{ 4-x}}}=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31352/).

So,

> **more precisely:** is it true, that for any $p=3k+1$ the sum of 3 cubic roots of sum of cosines (described above) can be expressed in real radicals?

what can be said about RHS in this case (say, about the number of nested radicals)?

Comment: (Answers to more informal question `just what's going on here?` would also be appreciated.)

Comment: (The question is quite long already, but maybe I'll add some thoughts/comments later...)

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612607/what-comes-after-cos-tfrac2-pi71-3-cos-tfrac4-pi71-3-cos

Comment: @GrigoryM: The thingie with $\cos(\pi/19)$ can be generalized. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065862/).

Comment: @GrigoryM: It seems $p=43$ belongs to a family ($p=31,43,109,157,\dots$) such that the three groups of numerators are _predictable_, having a _closed-form_. See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069520/).

Comment: A lot of neat stuff here. I upvoted everybody.

Comment: @GrigoryM: Noam Elkies has finally found an analogous quintic that uses $\cos \pi/11$. See this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/a/245677/12905).

Comment: @Tito Piezas III In what year did Ramanujan find the identity above?

Comment: Another identity from Ramanujan is: $$\sqrt[3]{\cos \frac 29\pi}+\sqrt[3]{\cos \frac 49\pi}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\frac 89\pi}=\sqrt[3]{\frac 12 \big(3\sqrt[3]9-6\big)}$$

Answer (score 15):

$\color{brown}{Update:}$

The question is: *Is it true, that for any $p=3k+1$  the sum of 3 cubic roots of sum of cosines can be expressed in real radicals?*

---

The answer is **Yes.** In general, given the roots $x_i$ of the general cubic equation,

$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0\tag0$$

then sums involving the cube roots of the $x_i$ can be given in the simple form,

$$(u+x_1)^{1/3}+(u+x_2)^{1/3}+(u+x_3)^{1/3} = \big(w\pm3\,\sqrt{d}\,^{1/3}\big)^{1/3}$$

where $u,w$ are the constants,

$$u = \frac{ab-9c\pm \sqrt{d}}{2(a^2-3b)}$$

$$w = -\frac{(2a^3-9ab+27c)+9\pm \sqrt{d}}{2(a^2-3b)}$$

and $d$ is the *negated* discriminant $D$,

$$-D = d = \frac{4(a^2-3b)^3-(2a^3-9ab+27c)^2}{27}$$

However, the fact $\pm\sqrt{d}$ gives ***two*** results implies Ramanujan's identity has a ***hidden partner***.

For example, given the minimal polynomial for $x=2\cos\big(\frac{2\pi}7\big)$, or $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1 = 0$. Since $\sqrt{d} = \sqrt{49} = \mp7$, then the negative case gives $(u=0,w =5)$ while the positive case gives $(u=1,w =-4)$, yielding the pair,

$$R_1=\sqrt[3]{0+2\cos\bigl(\tfrac{2\pi}{7}\bigr)}+\sqrt[3]{0+2\cos\bigl(\tfrac{4\pi}{7}\bigr)}+\sqrt[3]{0+2\cos\bigl(\tfrac{8\pi}{7}\bigr)} = \sqrt[3]{+5\color{blue}{-}3\,\sqrt[3]{7}}$$

$$R_2=\sqrt[3]{1+2\cos\bigl(\tfrac{2\pi}{7}\bigr)}+\sqrt[3]{1+2\cos\bigl(\tfrac{4\pi}{7}\bigr)}+\sqrt[3]{1+2\cos\bigl(\tfrac{8\pi}{7}\bigr)} = \sqrt[3]{-4\color{blue}{+}3\,\sqrt[3]{7}}$$

Some remarks. If the cubic has *all* real roots:

1. ... then discriminant $-D=+d$, and *$(u,w)$ are also real*.
2. ... with a *cyclic group*, then $d$ is a square, *so $(u,w)$ in fact are rational*.
3. ... then $a^2-3b=0$ never occurs, since this implies $-D =d = -(a^3-27c)^2$, so only one root $x_1$ is real.

These pairs are for other prime $p=6m+1$, covering my old [addendum](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1086331/4781) for $p=19$.

---

$\color{brown}{Old\; answer:}$

The general phenomenon can be explained by a beautiful cubic identity found by Ramanujan, of course. {Grigori M, ironically, you pointed out this identity in an [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612607/what-comes-after-cos-tfrac2-pi71-3-cos-tfrac4-pi71-3-cos?lq=1#comment1293565_612607) of mine.}

**I.** Given the three roots $x_i$ of,

$$x^3-ax^2+bx-1 = 0\tag1$$

then,

$$x_1^{1/3}+x_2^{1/3}+x_3^{1/3} = (a+6+3t)^{1/3}\tag2$$

where $t$ is a root of,

$$t^3-3(a+b+3)t-\big(ab+6(a+b)+9\big) = 0\tag3$$

The form of the $p=19$ suggests it is just a particular case of this identity. Note that,

$$y=2\Bigl(\cos\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{7\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{11\pi}{19}\bigr)\Bigr)$$

is a root of,

$$y^3+y^2-6y-7=0$$

One can then scale variables and make the constant term $c=-1$. I did so, and got the *exact* form as the one above.

**II.** Note that if $a+b+3=0$, then $(3)$ takes a particularly simple form. After some manipulation, I found that given,

$$x^3 + x^2 - (3 n^2 + n)x + n^3=0\tag4$$

then,

$$F_P = x_1^{1/3}+x_2^{1/3}+x_3^{1/3} = \sqrt[3]{-(6n+1)+3\sqrt[3]{nP}}\tag5$$

where $P = 9n^2+3n+1$. For $n = -1, 1, -2, 2$, we get the same cubics satisfied by the *sums of cosines* for $P=7,13,31,43,\dots$ thus explaining the simple sums,

$$F_7 =-\sqrt[3]{-5+3\sqrt[3]{7}} $$

$$F_{13} = \sqrt[3]{-7+3\sqrt[3]{13}} $$

and so on, though I cannot prove that the roots of $(4)$ are always sums of cosines when $P$ is prime. Maybe I'll ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @GrigoryM: I've now asked the question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068084/).

Comment: I actually used the cubic for $p=19$ and got the _same_ result as the guy from artofproblemsolving. Since the cubic is $y^3+y^2-6y-7=0$, you have to scale it by $y = 7^{1/3}x$ which explains the 3rd level of cube roots. I'm 100% sure he used Ramanujan's identity, but didn't tell, tsk, tsk.

Comment: Thank you. I need to think about it for some time.

Comment: One note, if $a^2 - 3b = 0$, then the cubic $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ can be written as $x^3 + 3\frac{a}{3}x^2 + 3\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^2 x + \left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^3 + c -   \left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^3$, and that means your cubic is just $(x-h)^3 + k$ for appropriate $h,k$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, I have some other comments & questions but I'll send them to you in an email.

Answer (score 14):

$\color{blue}{\text{Edited 9 Jun 2017:}}$

Let $p$ be a prime number congruent to 1 modulo 6, and 
$g$ a primitive root modulo $p$, i.e. a generator of the group $ \mathbb F_{p} ^ {\times} \cong C_{p-1} $.
By definition, put
$$
 S_p(g) = \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{p-4}3}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}g^{3k}\right) ,
S'_p(g) =\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{p-4}3}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}g^{3k+1}\right) \text{,   }
S''_p(g)  = \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{p-4}3}\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}g^{3k+2}\right) .
$$

In [this PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1b6hin85hmfl7c2/version1_8%20June%202017.pdf?dl=0)
 we prove the following result.

> **Theorem 1.** Suppose $p$ equals $9m^2+3m+1$ for some $m\in \mathbb Z$. Then for any primitive root $g$ we have
>   $$\sqrt[3]{S_p(g)} +  \sqrt[3]{S'_p(g)} +  \sqrt[3]{S''_p(g)} =\sqrt[3]{ 3\sqrt[3]{mp}-(6m+1) } . $$

*Warning:* I am not sure about my English. If you find some mistakes please write me.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to find such rationals $a,b,c,d$ so that,
$$(a+b\,x_1)^{1/3} + (a+b\,x_2)^{1/3} + (a+b\,x_3)^{1/3} = (c+\sqrt[3]{dp})^{1‌​/3}$$ 
So, we have identities for all primes $p=1\ mod\ 3$ such that $p<100$
$$\sqrt[3]{1+\sum_{k=0}^{5}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{19}\cdot2^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{1+\sum_{k=0}^{5}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{19}\cdot2^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{1+\sum_{k=0}^{5}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{19}\cdot2^{3k+2}) }=\sqrt[3]{8-3\sqrt[3]{19}}\qquad\\ \sqrt[3]{-1+\sum_{k=0}^{11}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{37}\cdot2^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{-1+\sum_{k=0}^{11}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{37}\cdot2^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{-1+\sum_{k=0}^{11}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{37}\cdot2^{3k+2}) }=\sqrt[3]{-10+3\sqrt[3]{37}}\qquad\\ \sqrt[3]{-1+\sum_{k=0}^{19}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{61}\cdot2^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{-1+\sum_{k=0}^{19}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{61}\cdot2^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{-1+\sum_{k=0}^{19}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{61}\cdot2^{3k+2}) }=\sqrt[3]{14-3\sqrt[3]{3\cdot 61}}\qquad\\$$

$$\sqrt[3]{1+\sum_{k=0}^{21}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{67}\cdot2^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{1+\sum_{k=0}^{21}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{67}\cdot2^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{1+\sum_{k=0}^{21}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{67}\cdot2^{3k+2})}=\sqrt[3]{-16+3\sqrt[3]{3\cdot 67}}\qquad\\ \sqrt[3]{-2+\sum_{k=0}^{25}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{79}\cdot3^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{-2+\sum_{k=0}^{25}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{79}\cdot3^{3k+1})}+\sqrt[3]{-2+\sum_{k=0}^{25}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{79}\cdot3^{3k+2})}=\sqrt[3]{-13+3\sqrt[3]{79}}\qquad\\ \sqrt[3]{3+\sum_{k=0}^{31}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{97}\cdot5^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{3+\sum_{k=0}^{31}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{97}\cdot5^{3k+1})}+\sqrt[3]{3+\sum_{k=0}^{31}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{97}\cdot5^{3k+2})}=\sqrt[3]{14-3\sqrt[3]{97}}
$$

$\color{blue}{\text{Added June 27:}}$

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{74}{43}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{\frac{74}{43}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{\frac{74}{43}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+2}) }=\sqrt[3]{\frac{392}{43}}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{5105}{11349}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{\frac{5105}{11349}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{\frac{5105}{11349}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+2}) }=\sqrt[3]{\frac{21}{1261}}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{-\frac{2306997866696}{1047656140569}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{-\frac{2306997866696}{1047656140569}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{-\frac{2306997866696}{1047656140569}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+2}) }=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{118149192000}{1908298981}}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{9658771264742899051}{5361029308457632889}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{\frac{9658771264742899051}{5361029308457632889}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{\frac{9658771264742899051}{5361029308457632889}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+2}) }=\sqrt[3]{\frac{60079542508626277}{3881990809889669}}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{1512950552654226074845360221799154}{22816093930106873589073278570630913}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1512950552654226074845360221799154}{22816093930106873589073278570630913}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1512950552654226074845360221799154}{22816093930106873589073278570630913}+\sum_{k=0}^{1}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{7}\cdot3^{3k+2}) }=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{9567191523845032860388297048}{16721690052047565734068821733}}$$
and so on.

Comment: I already gave the general formula as $$ (u+x_1)^{1/3} + (u+x_2)^{1/3} + (u+x_3)^{1/3} = (w+3\sqrt{d}\,^{1/3})^{1‌​/3}$$ where the $x_i$ are the roots of the cubic and $u,w$ are in terms of the coefficients. See [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1067992/4781) above. But these explicit relations are also nice.

Comment: I didn't use this formula because it gives only one solution.I think there are two identities for any $p$ but I can't proove it. For example:

$$\sqrt[3]{1+\sum_{k=0}^{5}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{19}\cdot2^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{1+\sum_{k=0}^{5}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{19}\cdot2^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{1+\sum_{k=0}^{5}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{19}\cdot2^{3k+2}) }=\sqrt[3]{8-3\sqrt[3]{19}}\qquad \sqrt[3]{2+\sum_{k=0}^{5}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{19}\cdot2^{3k}) }+\sqrt[3]{2+\sum_{k=0}^{5}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{19}\cdot2^{3k+1}) }+\sqrt[3]{2+\sum_{k=0}^{5}\cos(\frac{2\pi }{19}\cdot2^{3k+2}) }=\sqrt[3]{-1+3\sqrt[3]{19}}\qquad$$

Comment: The formula actually gives **two** solutions by using $\pm\sqrt{d}$. In fact, I gave two solutions in the example in my answer, one for $+\sqrt{7}$ and the other for $-\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: You are right, I was inattentived. I solved some diophantine equation and my solutions are equal yours.

Comment: Do you think you can find anything if there is a $5$th power version, $$(u+x_1)^{1/5}+(u+x_2)^{1/5}+\dots+(u+x_5)^{1/5} = (p+q\sqrt[5]{d})^{1/5}$$

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps it's false analogy.

Comment: Why do you think that exist such $u$ that RHS is so simple? It's not trivial statement.

Comment: Noam Elkies has finally found an analogous quintic that uses $\cos \pi/11$. See this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/a/245677/12905).

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $p=3k+1$. Then by a theorem of Gauss $4p=A^2+27B^2$ and cubic sums like $\displaystyle\sum_{t\in\mathbb Z/p}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi t^3}p\right)$ are roots of the equation $x^3-3px-Ap=0$. And if we have three roots $x_i$ of a cubic equation, Ramanujan's lemma gives the value of $\sqrt[3]{x_1}+\sqrt[3]{x_2}+\sqrt[3]{x_3}$. That's precisely what's going on, I believe.

Comment: I'll try to expand this answer later

Comment: Related: upd. in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/102736/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/a/31600/

Comment: Ramanujan's lemma works for any cubic eqn. However, I'm suspecting that for prime $p=3m+1$ where the roots $x_i$ involve the $p$th root of unity thus are sums of cosines, then I think one can always find rationals $a,b,c,d$ to the identity, $$(a+b\,x_1)^{1/3}+(a+b\,x_2)^{1/3}+(a+b\,x_3)^{1/3}=\big(c+\sqrt[3]{dp}\big)^{1/3}$$ There is a family of $p$ where $a=0$, and Ramanujan's $p=7$ was the simplest.

Answer (score 5):

(*Addendum to my answer.*) I just realized that given the $p=19$ identity cited by the OP,

$$\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{7\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{11\pi}{19}\bigr)}+\\
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{3\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{5\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{17\pi}{19}\bigr)}+\\
\sqrt[3]{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{9\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{13\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{15\pi}{19}\bigr)}=\\
\sqrt[3]{\tfrac12-3\sqrt[3]7+\tfrac32\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{49}+18\sqrt[3]7-25}+\tfrac32\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{49}+18\sqrt[3]7-44}}=0.815731\dots$$

a *small* tweak can give a simpler, but different one,

$$\sqrt[3]{ -\tfrac{1}{2}+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{7\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{11\pi}{19}\bigr)}+\\
\sqrt[3]{-\tfrac{1}{2}+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{3\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{5\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{17\pi}{19}\bigr)}+\\
\sqrt[3]{-\tfrac{1}{2}+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{9\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{13\pi}{19}\bigr)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{15\pi}{19}\bigr)}=\\ \sqrt[3]{-4+\tfrac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{19}}=0.1375504\dots$$

It's because there is only a *linear* transformation between the cubic involved in,

$$\sqrt{ a+ \sqrt{ a + \sqrt{ a-x}}}=x$$

and the cubic for,

$$y_1^{1/3}+y_2^{1/3}+y_3^{1/3} = \sqrt[3]{-(6n+1)+3\sqrt[3]{nP}}$$

with $P = 9n^2+3n+1$, and we use $n=\frac{1}{2}$.

See [these comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068084/a-little-more-on-sqrt3-cos-bigl-tfrac2-pi7-bigr-sqrt3-cos-bigl-tf?lq=1#comment2211402_1085795).

Comment: haha $n = 1/2$ ? so that's what breaks the integral normal basis thing and get you those $-1/2$ constant coefficient ?

Comment: @mercio: I'm still not sure how to get those constants in front of the cosines in the [other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065862/), but this one works. :)

Comment: wait... those two identities are different right ? why do you say it's a simplification ? this looks crazy anyway...

Comment: @mercio: Yes, they are different. I was being imprecise. I'll edit and phrase it another way.