# What's the explanation for these (infinitely many?) Ramanujan-type identities?

Tags: trigonometry, galois-theory, radicals, cubics

Define the function,

$$F(\beta) := \sqrt[3]{\beta+x_1}+\sqrt[3]{\beta+x_2}+\sqrt[3]{\beta+x_3}\tag1$$

where,

$$x_1 =2\cos\big(\tfrac{2\pi }{7}\big),\;x_2 =2\cos\big(\tfrac{4\pi }{7}\big),\;  x_3 =   2\cos\big(\tfrac{8\pi }{7}\big)$$

or the $x_i$ are the roots of the cubic $x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$. We have two nice identities,

$$F(0) = \sqrt[3]{5-3\sqrt[3]7}$$

$$F(1) = \sqrt[3]{-4+3\sqrt[3]7}$$

The first one is by Ramanujan.  (See *[The Problems Submitted by Ramanujan to the Journal of the Indian Mathematical Society](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.9228&rep=rep1&type=pdf)*, p. 9, by Bruce Berndt, et al.)

These two (and other pairs) can be explained by the negative and positive cases of $\pm \sqrt{d}$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1067992/4781). However, **davidoff303** [found a plethora](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1588508/4781) of others,

$$F\Big(\frac{74}{43}\Big) = 2\,\sqrt[3]\frac{7^2}{43}$$

$$F\Big(\frac{5105}{11349}\Big) = 3\,\sqrt[3]\frac{7}{11349}$$

$$F\Big(\frac{-2306997866696}{1047656140569}\Big) = -10980\,\sqrt[3]\frac{7^2}{1047656140569}$$

$$F\Big(\frac{9658771264742899051}{5361029308457632889}\Big)= 13\cdot 127\cdot 1381\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{5361029308457632889}}$$

and so on. Note that, for general rational $\beta$, then $\big(F(\beta)\big)^3$ is a root of a $9$th deg equation.

> **Q1**: Are there infinitely many rational $\beta$ such that $\big(F(\beta)\big)^3$ ***is also rational***, like the ones found by davidoff303? Is there a formula for $\beta$?

$\color{blue}{Update:}$

I formed the $9$th deg equation satisfied by $\big(F(\beta)\big)^3$. Acting on a hunch, it turns out that the $\beta$ used by davidoff303 satisfies the simple relation,

$$\beta^3-\beta^2-2\beta+1 =w^3\tag2$$

This can be transformed into an *elliptic curve*, and it has infinitely many rational points. And the $LHS$ of $(2)$ in fact is a factor of the discriminant of the $9$th deg eqn.

> **Q2**: Is it true that if rational $\beta$ satisfies $(2)$, then $\big(F(\beta)\big)^3$ is also rational?

Comment: This has definitely something to do with Kummer sums (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_sum) and the fact that the Galois group of the minimal polynomial of $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$ is a cyclic group with $\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}$ elements.

Comment: @davidoff303: How did you find the $\beta$? It's a vague feeling, but does the growth of $\beta$ involve an elliptic curve?

Comment: @davidoff303: I figured it out. There ***is*** an elliptic curve involved. However, I still don't know why it works.

Comment: In other words, (2) means $(\beta+x_1)(\beta+x_2)(\beta+x_3)=w^3$.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but $\beta=0$ satisfies $(2)$, but $(F(0))^3$ is not rational ? (though, it is a root of a degree $3$ polynomial)

Comment: @ccorn: Yes, it can also be expressed that way.

Comment: @mercio: I just noticed the same can be said for $\beta =1$. Maybe $(2)$ implies that $\big(F(\beta)\big)^3$ is a root of a cubic (instead of a nonic). Then there might be an additional condition such that this cubic has a linear factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there are $3$ ways to choose each of the cube roots, in general, $F(\beta)$ is a root of a degree $27$ polynomial whose coefficients are expressions in $\beta,(x_1+x_2+x_3),(x_1x_2,x_2x_3,x_3x_1),(x_1x_2x_3)$.

Since multiplying each root by $\zeta_3$ doesn't change the value of $F(\beta)^3$, this polynomial is in fact a polynomial of degree $9$ in $F(\beta)^3$.

Assume now that we have $(\beta+x_1)(\beta+x_2)(\beta+x_3) = w^3$.

Then the degree $9$ polynomial factors after extending our coefficients field with $w$, into a cubic and a sextic : gather in the cubic the three choices of roots giving $(\beta+x_1)^{1/3}(\beta+x_2)^{1/3}(\beta+x_3)^{1/3} = w$

Then, $F(\beta)^3 = (3\beta+x_1+x_2+x_3) + 6w + 3\sum_{i \neq j} (\beta+x_i)^\frac 23(\beta+x_j)^\frac 13 \\
= (3\beta+x_1+x_2+x_3) + 6w + 3w\sum_{i \neq j} (\beta+x_i)^\frac 13(\beta+x_j)^{-\frac 13}$

And so $(F(\beta)^3$ is rational if and only if the sum is. At this point, a choice of $F(\beta)$ among the $3$ possibilities is equivalent to a choice of only one term if the sum. Or equivalently, you go from one value to the others by multiplying $(\beta+x_2)^\frac 13$ by $\zeta_3$ and $(\beta+x_3)^\frac 13$ by $\zeta_3^2$

Split the sum into two parts $z_1 + z_2$ (one for each coset of $A_3$ in $S_3$). When applying this automorphism, one is multiplied by $\zeta_3$ and the other is multiplied by $\zeta_3^2$, so their product $z_1z_2$ has to be invariant, and indeed, $w^2z_1z_2 = 3\beta^2-2\beta-2+(3\beta-1)w+3w^2$.

If the original Galois group between $x_1,x_2,x_3$ had been $S_3$, things would have been more complicated, but here, since the Galois group is cyclic, $x_1/x_2+ x_2/x_3 + x_3/x_1$ is rational, and this implies that $z_1^3$ and $z_2^3$ are rational :

$\{(wz_i)^3\} = 9\beta^3-9\beta^2-11\beta+3w(3\beta^2-2\beta-2)+3w^2(3\beta-1) + \{2;9\}$

If one of them is $0$, then the other is $\pm 7$, and this corresponds to the $\beta = 0,1$ cases.

If not, then $F(\beta)^3$ is rational if and only if one of those two rational numbers is a cube (since their product is a nonzero cube, this is equivalent to both being a cube).

---

The map $(\beta,w) \mapsto \\
(X = 3\beta^2-2\beta-2+(3\beta-1)w+3w^2 ; \\
Y = 9\beta^3-9\beta^2-11\beta+3w(3\beta^2-2\beta-2)+3w^2(3\beta-1))$

is a rational isomorphism between the elliptic curves $E_1 : w^3 = (\beta+x_1)(\beta+x_2)(\beta+x_3)$ and $E_2 : (Y+2)(Y+9) = X^3$ (it can't be ramified, and the only preimage of the point at infinity from $E_2$ is the point at infinity with $\beta/w = 1$)

Since $Y+2$ has a triple pole at the point at infinity of $E_2$ and a triple zero at $(X=0,Y=-2)$, $Y+2$ is not a cube (there is no degree $1$ map from an elliptic curve into $\Bbb P^1$), but the extension obtained by adding a cube root of $Y+2$ is a $3$ fold unramified covering $f : E_3 \to E_2 \cong E_1$

Then the rational points on $E_1$ whose $F(\beta)^3$ is rational are (aside from the two exceptions with $X=0$) the images of the rational points on $E_3$.

Choose a rational point on $E_3$ (such as any example where $F(\beta)$ is a cube, or the rational point above the point at infinity of $E_2$) so we can have a group law on $E_3$ and $E_2$.

If $\hat f : E_2 \to E_3$ is the dual map to $f$ then $f \circ \hat f = [3]$, so $f(E_3(\Bbb Q))$ is a subgroup of $E_2(\Bbb Q)$ that has to contain $[3](E_2(\Bbb Q))$

If you name $u = (Y+2)^\frac 13,v = (Y+9)^\frac 13$, then $E_3$ is given by $v^3=u^3+7$ and $f : E_3 \to E_2$ is given by $(X = uv, Y = u^3-2)$. After composing this with the isomorphism $E_2 \to E_1$ (that I didn't compute), you get a nice rational algebraic parametrization by $E_3$ of the points you want, $(u,v) \mapsto (\beta,w,F(\beta)^3)$

---

From here on, things might be different with other choices of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ or other base fields.

According to http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/441/d/2

$E_2(\Bbb Q)$ 's torsion subgroup has order $3$ and is generated by $Q_1 = (X=0, Y=-2) = (\beta = 1, w = -1)$. Since $Y+9$ is not a cube, it doesn't have a rational preimage in $E_3$ and $F(1)^3$ is not rational.

The other point of order $3$ is $2Q_1 = Q_2 = (X=0, Y=-9) = (\beta = 0, w = 1)$ and is in the same case.

$E_2(\Bbb Q)$ has rank $1$ and its free part is generated by $R = (X=2,Y= -1) = (\beta = \frac {74}{43}, w = - \frac {29}{43})$. Since $Y+2$ and $Y+9$ are nonzero cubes, it has a rational preimage in $E_3$, and $F(\frac {74}{43})^3$ is rational.

This is enough to determine that the subgroup of "good" points is generated by $(X=2,Y= -1)$. 
For example $2R = (X = -\frac{20}9, Y = -\frac{118}{27}) = (\beta = \frac {5105}{11349}, w = - \frac {2521}{11349})$, and so on.

Since $E_3$ also has a group law, there are addition formulas that combine triplets of rationals $(\beta,w,F(\beta)^3)$, so if you compute those formulas, you get an easy way to generate the points you want.

---

As you noticed, $\tau : (\beta,w) \mapsto (-\frac 1{\beta-1},\frac w{\beta-1})$ is the translation by $Q_2$ (a point of order $3$), and thus for any rational point $P$ on $E_1$, exactly one of $\{P,\tau(P),\tau^2(P)\}$ has a rational preimage in $E_3$ (has $F(\beta)^3$ rational).

Comment: Thanks! A small question though. I've realized that $\beta^3-\beta^2-2\beta+1 = w^3$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition such that $\big(F(\beta)\big)^3$ is rational. For example, $\beta=9/5$. Is there an explicit rational Diophantine equation that $\beta = 74/34$ satisfies, but $\beta = 9/5$ does not?

Comment: after looking at http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/441/d/2 the generator they give corresponds to $\beta = 74/43$, it gives $X=2,Y=-1$ which has a rational preimage because $Y+2$ and $Y+9$ are cubes. However the torsion points $(X=0,Y=-2)$ and $(X=0,Y=-9)$ don't have rational preimages because $7$ and $-7$ are not cubes, so the "good" subgroup has index $3$ in $E_2(\Bbb Q)$. Using the multiplication formulas with the torsion subgroup should give you, from a $(\beta,w)$, formulas for the $3$ candidate $\beta$, only one of which is good

Comment: instead of a diphantine equation, I think it's possible that there is a simple modular condition on $\beta$ that tells you by which torsion element you have to compose to get to a good rational point.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that if $\beta_1 = \frac{p}{p+q}$ satisfies $\beta^3-\beta^2-2\beta+1  = \text{cube}$, then so does $\beta_2 = \frac{p+q}{q}$. For example, $\beta_1 = \frac{31}{74}$ and $\beta_2 =\frac{74}{43}$ though usually (excluding the case $\beta = 1/2,\,2$) only one of them yields a cubic with a rational root.

Comment: also $\beta_{3}=-\frac{q}{p}$

Comment: @davidoff303: What were your guidelines to find your $\beta$? I guess it is not brute search since the numbers are too big. Did you use $\beta^3-\beta^2-2\beta+1 =w^3$?

Comment: @mercio: In my answer below, can you show that $(1),(2),(3)$ simultaneously holds for infinitely many rational points?

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: I used PARI/GP: http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr

Comment: @davidoff303: Ah, thanks. By the way, I checked and the _rational_ $\big(F(\beta)\big)^3$ phenomenon works for $d = 7,19,37$. I'm not sure if it also works for $d=13,31,43$ since the search bounds I used may have been too small. Would you like to check with PARI? If you find anything, can kindly you post it as a new answer here? (Only the short ones, pls.)

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: I will try.

Comment: @davidoff303: I found the general formula. It works for ***any*** cubic $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$. For example, for $d=13$ we have $$\sqrt[3]{p+x_1}+\sqrt[3]{p+x_2}+\sqrt[3]{p+x_3} = \sqrt[3]{15^3 q}$$ where $p = \frac{-12901}{20367}$ and $q = \frac{-13}{20367}$ and the $x_i$ are the roots of $x^3+x^2-4x+1=0$ and can be expressed as sums of $\cos\big(\tfrac{\pi\,k}{13}\big)$.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: it's very interesting! did you use elliptic curve?

Comment: @davidoff303: Well, yes, it was a point on an elliptic curve. I may ask the general question in MathOverflow. I'll send you the link if I do so.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: ok, it's interesting for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long comment/addendum to **mercio**’s answer. Given rational solutions to,
$$\beta^3-\beta^2-2\beta+1 = w^3\tag1$$
As pointed out by mercio, if we define,
$$X = 3\beta^2-2\beta-2+(3\beta-1)w+3w^2 \\Y = 9\beta^3-9\beta^2-11\beta+3w(3\beta^2-2\beta-2)+3w^2(3\beta-1)$$
then this obeys the elegant relation,
$$(Y+2)(Y+9) = X^3$$ 
However, if we require $\beta$ such that
$$Y+2 = u^3\tag2$$
$$Y+9 = v^3\tag3$$
holds separately, then we can define $\big(F(\beta)\big)^3$ as,
$$\big(F(\beta)\big)^3 = \frac{3(t+19)(u+v)+(3uv+7)(27u^4v-63u^3+105uv-196)}{t+19}\tag4$$
where,
$$t=27(u^3+3)(u^3+4)$$
Thus, if $\beta$ satisfies the rational Diophantine conditions $(2),(3)$ in addition to $(1)$, then $\big(F(\beta)\big)^3$ is rational.

**Example.** Let $\beta = \tfrac{74}{43}$, we get $u=1,\;v=2,\;t=540,$ and using formula $(4)$,
$$\big(F(\tfrac{74}{43})\big)^3 = \frac{2^3\cdot7^2}{43}$$
the same as in the post above. All six examples in the post obey $(1)$, but *only the last four obey all* $(1), (2),(3)$. Presumably there are infinitely many rational $\beta$ that obey all three conditions, but I do not know how to prove it so.

Comment: @mercio: By the way, how did you find $X,Y$? For example, if we use the cubic involved with $\cos(\pi/19)$, and solve, $$t^3-t^2-6t+7 = w^3$$ this has infinitely many solutions. Does this also have a $X,Y$ such that $$(Y+a)(Y+b) = X^3$$ and $-a+b=19$?

Comment: @mercio: I figured out the general case. :)   So I'm making a question for $d=19$.

Comment: (I didn't get pinged) I don't think anything should change much in the first two paragraphs with $d=19$. I found $Y$ by looking carefully at $F(\beta)^3$. The sum was the source of the potential non-rationality, and looking at how the Galois group acted on its terms naturally leads to $z_1$ and $z_2$ and figuring out that they live in the same cubic radical extension so they both need to be cubes.

Comment: finding the formulas for $(wz_i)^3$ and $(w^2z_1z_2)$ was just a matter of computation and replacing the symmetric expressions of the $x_i$ by the coefficients of their cubic.

Comment: @mercio: The question is done. Can you kindly look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844225/generalizing-ramanujans-cube-roots-of-cubic-roots-identities).