# A Ramanujan-type trigonometric identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, trigonometry, polynomials, nested-radicals

At the end of the following article:

http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2013-85-1/15/15.pdf

It is asserted that the russian mathematician, Sergey Markelov, in private communication, told them that he discovered the following trigonometric identity

$\sqrt[3]{\sin \frac{2\pi}{7}} + \sqrt[3]{\sin \frac{4\pi}{7}} + \sqrt[3]{\sin \frac{8\pi}{7}} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt[3]{7}}{3} - 2 +\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{7} - 4}+\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{7} - 5}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[6]{7}}$

However, there isn't further reference about this remarkable identity. How to prove it?

Comment: Cubic Gauss sums, I would say.

Comment: Can you tell me, please, if $\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[6]{7}}$ is  a second factor  in RHS (in which case it would be better for the reader to put it as first factor) or it must be inside the large cubic root?

Comment: @Fractional Inquirer: You do not have to answer me any more. I already found out that it is a factor.

Comment: Tito Piezas III gave a general solution to these kinds of identities, and Ramanujan also gave a less general solution. But it only works for “simple” trigonometric identities, and cubics.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/644003/

Comment: The link presented in the article is now obsolete.I tried to find Sergey Markelov's contact information, but alas, couldn't find anything. He appears to be a mathematics educator, not a researcher