# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $9m^2+3m+1$ where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: prime-numbers

This question is related  to Theorem $1$ in
[my old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1582234).

All primes $p=9m^2+3m+1$ with $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ up to $1000$ can be found in 
[this paper](http://davidoff303.ru/Generalizing%20Ramanujan's%20trigonometric%20identity.pdf) 
(see Table $1$ on the  page $7$).

Comment: It seems there are infinitely many such prime numbers.

Comment: If there were a theory about when a prime is congruent to a sum of quadratic residues it might help.

Comment: The only non-trivial result in this context , apart from Dirichlet's theorem that every arithmetic progression $an+b$ with coprime $a$ and $b$ produces infinite many primes, is that there are infinite many primes of the form $a^2+b^4$, but this is a polynomial with two unknowns.

Answer (score 4):

The Bunyakovsky conjecture implies that there are infinite many primes of this form, but the only solved case is degree $1$ (Dirichlet's theorem).

For no integer polynomial with degree $d>1$, it is known that it produces infinite many primes.