# More on primes $p=u^2+27v^2$ and roots of unity

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, prime-numbers, roots-of-unity

Given,

$$p=u^2+27v^2=6m+1\tag1$$

and the cubic,

$$x^3+x^2-2mx+N=0\tag2$$

with its constant expressed in terms of $(1)$ as,

$$N = \frac{1}{27}(1-3p\pm2pu)\tag3$$

and the sign $\pm u$ chosen appropriately. (The discriminant is $D=-108p^2v^2$, so all real roots.) Starting with Ramanujan's [general cubic identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1067992/4781), they are a special case, yielding the simple,

$$(a+b\,x_1)^{1/3}+(a+b\,x_2)^{1/3}+(a+b\,x_3)^{1/3}=\big(c+\sqrt[3]{dp}\big)^{1/3}\tag4$$

for some rational $a,b,c,d$.

***Question:*** Is it true that if $p=u^2+27v^2=6m+1$ is prime, then a root of $(2)$ is *always* a sum of the $p$th *root of unity* of form,

$$x = \sum_{n=1}^{2m}\,\exp\Bigl(\frac{2\pi\, i\, k^n}{p}\Bigr)$$

for some integer $k$?

***Example:*** We have $p=127=10^2+27\cdot1^2=6\cdot21+1$, so

$$x^3+x^2-(2\times21)x+80=0,\quad\quad x =\sum_{n=1}^{2\times21}\,\exp\Bigl(\frac{2\pi\, i\, (5^n)}{127}\Bigr)$$

with all three roots $x_i$ yielding,

$$(-2+x_1)^{1/3}+(-2+x_2)^{1/3}+(-2+x_3)^{1/3}=-\big(19-3\,\sqrt[3]{254}\big)^{1/3} = -0.097378\dots$$

***P.S.*** This generalizes *Question 3* of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069520/), and is also related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068084/).

Comment: cf. statement in the upd. of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/102736/

Comment: (and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/31485/ is, of course, related)

Comment: and your $k$ is always an element of order $(p-1)/3$ in $\mathbb Z/p^\times$, I guess

Comment: (Looks like we already have all pieces of the puzzle and they start to fit together... — but I haven't yet solved it...)

Comment: @GrigoryM: Thanks for the links! Yes, getting close. Given the cubic eqn $(2)$ and the Ramanujan-type $(4)$, I'm trying to find a closed-form for the rationals $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Explicit formulas would be very nice indeed...

Comment: @GrigoryM: I found the general formula. Kindly see the [updated answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1067992/4781).