# How does $\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{3}\cos\left (\frac13\arccos\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\right)+\frac23$ simplify to $1+2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}$?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

$$\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{3}\cos\left (\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left (\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}  \right )  \right )+\frac{2}{3}$$
This is actually a solution for $x^3-2x^2-x+1$, and I tried to solve and got that solution.

And I have found this simplified solution $$1+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)$$
on the internet. However, I do not know how to even start to simplify it.

Any help what are the steps for that simplification?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734564)

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589364/simplify-frac4-sqrt73-cos-left-frac13-arccos-frac1-sqrt28?rq=1

Comment: If you can find a $y$ with $\arccos y = {1 \over 3} \arccos {1 \over 2\sqrt{7}}$, then $3 \arccos y = \arccos {1 \over 2\sqrt{7}}$. Taking cosine of both sides and using the formula for $\cos 3 \theta$ you get $4y^3 - 3y = {1 \over 2\sqrt{7}}$...

Comment: Can you show that both expressions are zeros of your polynomial? I suspect that any proof is going to look like essentially like this.

Comment: The first one you could check is actually a zero by Cardano's formula. For the second one, I just plug it into the computer to check if it is a zero. And if you see the decimal approximation you could tell they are actually the same.

Comment: Possible hint: $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)$

Comment: @junjios: That wouldn't be sufficient, because the polynomial has three real roots.

Comment: I can show that $1 + 2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})$ is a solution to the cubic given. But that is not enough.

Comment: @Dan As I pointed out in my answer it suffices to show both zeros are greater than or equal to $\frac{2+\sqrt 7}{3}$. This is actually not difficult, I'm going to edit my answer later.

Comment: @sku It is (almost) enough. See my comment above and the end of my answer. I would be happy to see your solution!

Comment: @junjios nice work u done here. but, I am attempting to prove by the polynomial idea is not what I am trying to get. Maybe even if we want to use the polynomial to prove, I think we should solve the polynomial and hope to get this simplified answer. btw, I am just a high school student, I am not that skilled in dealing with such questions.

Comment: @junjios I have looked at ur answer again, I feel stupid now. ur answer should be enough.

Comment: @MinaBasilious Please don't feel stupid! I understand that such a proof can be confusing when you first see it. If you get the idea now, this is really what MSE should be all about.

Comment: Confirmed `True` by *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting together the pieces discussed:

$\textbf{Step 1:}$

let $x = \frac13\arccos\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}} \implies 4\cos^3 x - 3 \cos x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{28}}$

let $y = \frac{2\sqrt{7}}{3}\cos\left (\frac13\arccos\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\right)+\frac23 \implies \frac{3y-2}{\sqrt{28}} = \cos x$

Substituting for $\cos x$ in first equation we get after simplification: $y^3 -2y^2 -y + 1 = 0$ .. Eqn (1)

$\textbf{Step 2:}$

Let $a = \cos \frac{2\pi}{7}, b = \cos \frac{\pi}{7}, c = \cos \frac{\pi}{14}$

We have $1 + 2\cos \frac{2\pi}{7} = 1 + 2a = 1 + 2(2b^2 - 1) = 4b^2 - 1$

Substituting this in Eqn (1) we get:

$(4b^2 - 1)^3 -2(4b^2 - 1)^2 - (4b^2 - 1) + 1 = 0$

Simplifying we get: $64b^6 - 80b^4 + 24b^2 -1 = 0$ ... Eqn(2)

$\textbf{Step 3:}$

$\cos 7t = \Re (\cos 7t + i\sin 7t) = \Re (\cos t + i\sin t)^7$

After simplifying and collecting real terms on right we get:

$\cos 7t = \cos t(64\cos^6 t - 112\cos^4 t + 56 \cos^2 t - 7)$ and substituting $t = \frac{\pi}{14}$ and noting $c = \cos \frac{\pi}{14}$
we get:

$64c^6 -112c^4 +56c^2 - 7 = 0$ ... Eqn(3)

We know $2c^2 = 1 + b$.

So we get $8(1+b)^3 - 28(1+b)^2 + 28(1+b) - 7 = 8b^3 -4b^2 - 4b + 1 = 0$

$\implies (8b^3 -4b)^2 = (4b^2-1)^2 \implies 64b^6 - 80b^4 + 24b^2 -1 = 0$

Thus we know $1+2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}$ is a solution to Eqn (2)

$\textbf{Step 4:}$
We still have to prove that these two roots have the same value. For that we note that the derivative of the polynomial is given by
$$3y^2-4y-1$$
which has zeros $\frac{2\pm\sqrt 7}{3}$. It follows that $y^3-2y^2-y+1$ is strictly increasing in $\left[\frac{2+\sqrt 7}{3},\infty\right)$ and hence it has at most one zero in this interval. In the previous steps we have seen that $\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{3}\cos\left (\frac13\arccos\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\right)+\frac23$ and $1+2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}$ both solve $y^3-2y^2-y+1=0$.

Moreover, we have
$$0\leq \frac 13\arccos\frac{1}{2\sqrt 7}\leq\frac\pi 3$$
which implies
$$\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{3}\cos\left (\frac13\arccos\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\right)+\frac23\geq\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{3}\frac 12+\frac 23=\frac{2+\sqrt 7}{3}.$$
On the other hand we see that $\frac{2\pi}{7}<\frac{\pi}{3}$. This implies
$$1+2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}>1+2\cos\frac\pi3=2>\frac{2+\sqrt 7}{3}.$$
We can therefore conclude that they must indeed be equal.

Comment: Thanks, this is really nicely done! I've corrected two minor typos in step 1 and added my part of the proof so that we have the complete proof in one answer now.

Answer (score 3):

So, the following proof is not complete but I'm posting it anyway, because it's too long for the comments and I hope someone will be able to fill in the missing part.

We check that $1+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)$ is a solution to $x^3-2x^2-x+1=0$. For that we compute
$$\left(1+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\right)^3-2\left(1+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\right)^2-\left(1+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\right)+1\\
=8\cos^3\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+4\cos^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-4\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-1\\
=2\left(\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)+3\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\right)+2\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)\right)-4\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-1\\
=2\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)+2\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+1=0.$$

To obtain the third line you can use the identities $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$ and $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$. Now, I don't actually know why the last part equals zero. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590127/447852) answer, it is a well known fact which is non-trivial. I haven't come up with a reliable source so far though.

Finally, you can argue that the polynomial has at most one zero in $\left[\frac{2+\sqrt{7}}{3},\infty\right)$. So, it suffices to show that both expressions are greater than $\frac{2+\sqrt{7}}{3}$.

Comment: @sku and me have got a complete answer to the question now. Since this proof is incomplete I recommend to accept sku's answer.

Comment: To show that the last expression is indeed $0$, you can note that this is the real part of the sum of all $7$-th roots of unity $\sum_{a = 0}^6 e^{2\pi ia/7}$, and it a very easy fact that this sum is zero (since, for example, it remains unchanged after being multiplied by $e^{2 \pi i /7}\neq 1$).

Comment: @CJDowd Of course, thank you for pointing it out. This really should have been quite obvious, but I guess I just didn't look at it closely enough, because I expected it to be difficult. You're very welcome to edit my answer accordingly, otherwise I can also do it later (probably at the weekend).

Answer (score 1):

The equation as given is a bit diffifult to work with. Things are less cumbersome if you define $x=y+1$, and then the cubic equation takes the form

$y^3+y^2-2y-1=0.$

With this form we show that the roots are twice the cosines of rational multiples of $\pi$.

**Method 1**

We plug in $y=2\cos\theta$ and multiply through by $\sin\theta$ to get

$8\cos^3\theta\sin\theta+4\cos^2\theta\sin\theta-4\cos\theta\sin\theta-\sin\theta=0.$  (Eq. 1)

And now apply the trigonometric sum-product relation iteratively:

$2\cos u\sin v=\sin(u+v)-\sin(u-v)$

So:

$2\cos\theta\sin\theta=\sin(2\theta)$

$4\cos^2\theta\sin\theta=2\cos\theta\sin(2\theta)=\sin(3\theta)+\sin\theta$

(Watch your signs: the coefficient of $\theta$ in $u-v$ is negative.)

$8\cos^3\theta\sin\theta=2\cos\theta(\sin(3\theta)+\sin\theta)=\sin(4\theta)+2\sin(2\theta)$

Plugging these into Eq. 1 gives

$[\sin(4\theta)+2\sin(2\theta)]+[\sin(3\theta)+\sin\theta]-2\sin(2\theta)-\sin\theta=0$

And then a miracle occurs: several terms cancel each other and all that remains is

$\sin(4\theta)+\sin(3\theta)=0.$

Thus $\sin(4\theta)=-\sin(3\theta)$ snd we conclude that $4\theta+3\theta$ must be a multiple of $2\pi$ or $4\theta-3\theta$ must be an odd multiple of $\pi$. Since $\theta=$ any multiple of $\pi$ implies $y=2\cos\theta=\pm2$ and this fails to satisfy the original cubic equation, the correct roots must be the remaining $\theta$ values divisible by $2\pi/7$ giving $y\in\{2\cos(2\pi/7),2\cos(4\pi/7),2\cos(6\pi/7)\}.$

**Method 2**

If one root of an odd-degree polynomial equation over the integers has the form $2\cos\theta$, Galois theory predicts that conjugate roots having the form $2\cos2^k\theta$ exist for as many values of $k$ as would be required to match the Galois symmetry of the equation.

Then if $y=2\cos\theta$ is indeed a root of our cubic equation, so should be $y^2-2=2\cos(2\theta)$.

So given

$y^3+y^2-2y-1=0$

we test whether

$(y^2-2)^3+(y^2-2)^2-2(y^2-2)-1=0.$

$y^6-5y^4+6y^2-1=0$

We have $y^3=-y^2+2y+1$, so $y^6=(-y^2+2y+1)^2=y^4-4y^3+2y^2+4y+1$ giving

$-4y^4-4y^3+8y^2+4y=-4y\color{blue}{(y^3+y-2y-1)}=0$

where the blue factor is zero by hypothesis and thus each root $y=2\cos\theta$ must be accompanied by a root $y^2-2=2\cos(2\theta)$.

So we have a sequence of roots

$y=2\cos\theta,y^2-2=2\cos(2\theta),y^4-4y^2+2=2\cos(4\theta),...$

where (with the cubic equation being irreducible), $y$ can't match $y^2-2$ and neither of these can match $y^4-4y^2+2=(y-1)(y^3+y^2-2y-1)+(-y^2-y+1)=-y^2-y+1$. So the argument doubling gives a cyclic sequence of the three roots and therefore $y=2\cos\theta$ is also $y=2\cos(8\theta)$.

By this method $\cos\theta=\cos(8\theta)$ and thus $(8\pm1)\theta$ must be a multiple of $2\pi$. But $\cos(2\pi/9)+\cos(4\pi/9)+\cos(8\pi/9)=0$ (the second term is also $\cos(-4\pi/9)$ and the arguments $-4\pi/9,2\pi/9,8\pi/9$ are equally spaced within the trigonometric period), and the roots should sum to $-1$. Therefore $y=2\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is forced to be a multiple of $2\pi/7$.

Neither method specifies *which* multiple of $2\pi/7$ corresponds to the specific root value given in the question. That cannot be done by algebra or trigonometry alone. We must appeal to (the principal branch of) the inverse cosine being defined in such a way that

$-(1/3)+(2\sqrt7)/3\cos[\frac13\arccos(\frac1{2\sqrt7})]=2\cos(2\pi/7).$

Comment: Wow, these are valuable insights. It's been a while since I've done some Galois theory (I'm working on partial differential equations now) so I don't understand method 2 completely. Also, if understand correctly, this approach only works since all zeros of the original polynomial are between $-1$ and $3$? Otherwise, we just couldn't see them with the expression $1+2\cos\theta$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The transformation $y\to y^2-2$ can shuttle between roots only if the orbit is bounded, which requires $|y|\le2$ in the reals.

Answer (score 0):

Conjecture without proof.

Let $a,b,c,f,k,m\in \mathbb{Z}$. If for irreducible cubic $-f+ax+bx^2+cx^3=0$ exist integer solution of system $$ \begin{cases}
a^2 + 3 b f = k\\
a b + 9 c f = k\\
b^2 - 3 a c = k
\end{cases} $$
then exist factorization of cubic over extension $\cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{km})$ and $x$ is linearly dependent on $\cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{km})$.

Examples code for W.Mathematica:

```
Factor[1 - x - 2 x^2 + x^3, Extension -> Cos[2 Pi/(7)]]
Factor[1 - x - 2 x^2 + x^3, Extension -> Cos[2 Pi/(7*4)]]
Factor[-1 + x + 4 x^2 + x^3, Extension -> Cos[2 Pi/(13)]]
Factor[-1 + x + 4 x^2 + x^3, Extension -> Cos[2 Pi/(13*2)]]
```