# solution of nested radical $\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{7-2x} } } =x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

This question is from my friend. he think that there is trigonometry involved to this equation.

$\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{7-2x} } } =x$

that is from  $\ \ \ x = \sqrt{7+2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt...} } }} } }$

I try to compare between this nested radical and Ramanujan's nested radicals form ,but  solution is for all positive terms.

Thank you for all comments , thank you so much

Comment: Which one are you trying to solve / evaluate?

Comment: @ElliotG Assuming the second thing exists, it would be a solution to the first equation.

Comment: A similar question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588659/an-infinite-nested-radical-problem) where $x =  4\cos \tfrac{2\pi}{7} +1 =3.4939\dots$

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{7-2x} } } &=x\\
7+2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{7-2x} }  &=x^2\\
2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{7-2x} }  &=x^2-7\\
4\left(7-2\sqrt{7-2x} \right)  &=x^4-14x^2+49\\
-8\sqrt{7-2x}   &=x^4-14x^2+21\\
64(7-2x)   &=x^8-28x^6+238x^4-588x^2+441\\
0   &=x^8-28x^6+238x^4-588x^2+128x-7\\
0&=\left(x^2+2x-7\right)\left(x^3-x^2-9x+1\right)^2
\end{align}$$
where a CAS helped with the last factoring. Based on the initial equation, $$\sqrt{7}<x<\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{7}}$$ and you can separately analyze that $x^2+2x-7$ has no zeros in this range. The other factor, $x^3-x^2-9x+1$, has one positive zero in this interval. As the root of a cubic, it is expressible in radicals if you want to use [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method).

If the original equation has a solution at all, it must be this root. It remains to check that this solution actually solves the original equation.

Comment: I was finishing typing when your answer arrived !

Answer (score 4):

I hope and wish that you will get a simpler solution. For the time being, here is mine.

I started writing $$\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{7-2y} } } =x$$ which I solved for $y$; this gives $$y=\frac{1}{128} \left(-x^8+28 x^6-238 x^4+588 x^2+7\right)$$ Replacing $y$ by $x$ and expanding leads to $$x^8-28 x^6+238 x^4-588 x^2+128 x-7=0$$ I suspected that this could be factorized and, after some attempts, a CAS found that this reduces to $$(x^2+2 x-7)(x^3-x^2-9 x+1)^2=0$$ As alex.jordan answered, because of the acceptable range, the solution corresponds to one of the roots of $x^3-x^2-9 x+1=0$. Using Cardano method, we know that there are three real roots. Using the [trigonometric method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_method_for_three_real_roots) for solving the cubic equation when three real roots are present, we arrive for the only acceptable root to the result $$x=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4\sqrt{7}}{3}  \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(3
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)\approx 3.49396$$ which is almost equal to $\frac 72$ and to $\sqrt{7+2 \sqrt{7}}\approx 3.50592$ !!

Comment: Alternatively, $x =  4\cos \tfrac{2\pi}{7} +1 =3.4939\dots$  :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. Thanks for pointing out this ... what I totally missed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint assume it to be $x$ and find the relation between $x$ and $x^2,x^3$ You will get it. If its trigo then it can be related to $\cos\theta$

Answer (score 0):

I notice that $ x^3-x^2-9 x+1=0 $ has three roots:

$ x_1=1-4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)=-2.60388... $

$ x_2=1+4 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{7}\right)=3.49396... $

$ x_3=1-4 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{7}\right)=0.109916... $

Therefore, the above result $ \sqrt{7+2 \sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{7-2 \left(1+4 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{7}\right)\right)}}}=1+4 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{7}\right) $ can be extended to:

$ \sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{7+2 \left(-1+4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)\right)}}}=-1+4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right) = -x_1 $

$ \sqrt{7+2 \sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{7-2 \left(1+4 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{7}\right)\right)}}}=1+4 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{7}\right) =x_2 $

$ \sqrt{7-2 \sqrt{7+2 \sqrt{7-2 \left(1-4 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{7}\right)\right)}}}=1-4 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{7}\right) =x_3 $