# How to solve this nested radical : $ \sqrt{a-y\sqrt{a+y\sqrt{a-y\sqrt{\cdots}}}} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-writing, nested-radicals

I want to know how to solve nested radicals of the following form:

$$ \sqrt{a-y\sqrt{a+y\sqrt{a-y\sqrt{\cdots}}}} $$

The repetition of signs is $ -,+,- $

Comment: This - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596824/solution-of-nested-radical-sqrt72-sqrt7-2-sqrt7-2x-x?rq=1 - might help.

Answer (score 10):

Set
$$x = \sqrt{a-y\sqrt{a+y\sqrt{a-y\sqrt{\cdots}}}}.$$
Then you have
$$x = \sqrt{a-y\sqrt{a+yx}}.$$
Squaring both sides and collecting terms:
$$x^2 - a = -y\sqrt{a+yx}.$$
Squaring both sides again:
$$(x^2 - a)^2 = {y^2}(a + yx).$$
It remains to solve for $x$.  Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [JOSE ARNALDO BEBITA DRIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28816/jose-arnaldo-bebita-dris) post, we can solve the equation pretending that the $a$ is variable and solving quadratic equation for it. Then we will find $x$ in terms of $a$ and $y$. The result is:
$$x = \frac{-y\pm\sqrt{4 a - 3 y^2}}{2} \text{ or } x=\frac{y\pm\sqrt{4 a + y^2} }{2}.$$
Plug each obtained solution into the original equation and one of them will be the exact solution to our nested root problem or just notice that only root can be $x=\dfrac{-y+\sqrt{4 a - 3y^2}}{2}$.