# Simplifying $\frac{2\sqrt{19}}{3}\cos{\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos{\frac{7}{\sqrt{76}}}\right)}-\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

Using Vieta's Trignometric Solutions, I am getting $$\dfrac{2\sqrt{19}}{3}\cos{\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\arccos{\dfrac{7}{\sqrt{76}}}\right)}-\dfrac{1}{3}\tag{1}$$ And it is also equal to $$2\left(\cos\left(\frac {4\pi}{19}\right)+\cos\left(\frac {6\pi}{19}\right)+\cos\left(\frac {10\pi}{19}\right)\right)\tag{2}$$

**My Question:** How would you get from $(1)$ to $(2)$, and is there a way to generalize it? Anything helps!

Comment: Hm... they aren't equal

Comment: I edited the question. Now, they are :)

Comment: It would help to know the equation from which you got $(1)$

Comment: $y^3+y^2-6y-7$.

Comment: OK, we have to show that $(2)$ is a root of the cubic. Not sure, whether there is another way to come from $(1)$ to $(2)$

Comment: Oh... But $(2)$ is already a root of $x^3+x^2-6x-7$. I just want to know if there is a way to get from $(1)$ to $(2)$... It should be possible, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41949/discussion-between-peter-and-frank).

Comment: see here google will help you

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31352/proving-2-cos-frac4-pi19-cos-frac6-pi19-cos-frac10-pi19

Comment: In your previous question you got $(2)\mapsto(1)$, and I do not think there is an easy way to spot $(1)\mapsto (2)$.